# One To Many relationship unsuccessful; throws error message

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA and Hibernate and have this following problem in my Implementation.

This is the code i have implemented:

Car class -> categoryIDFS colum:

```
@Column(name = "categoryIDFS")
private Category category;
```

Category class one my many implementation:

```
@OneToMany
List<Car> carsCategory;
```

Error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [ch.bbw.eb.hibernatecrud.controller.BrandController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:217) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1015) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:941) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80) ~[jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55) ~[jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at ch.bbw.eb.hibernatecrud.repository.BrandRepository.setup(BrandRepository.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at ch.bbw.eb.hibernatecrud.repository.BrandRepository.<init>(BrandRepository.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at ch.bbw.eb.hibernatecrud.controller.BrandController.<init>(BrandController.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ch.bbw.eb.hibernatecrud.model.Category, at table: cars, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(categoryIDFS)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:486) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:343) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:938) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Car` should be mapped to `Category` as **many-to-one**: every car has a category and one category can have multiple cars.

In class Car:

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "categoryIDFS")
prvate Category category;
```

In  class Category:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category") 
private List<Car> cars;  // all the cars belong to this category
```

Note, you need to use `@JoinColumn` with `@ManyToOne`. Not just `@Column`